# How to fix ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error in Robot framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have to test vizzes on webpage page. When I mouse over the vizz **Zoom** button appears and I have to click on this button. For vizzes which are at the top of the page I can click on **Zoom** button. But I cannot click on **Zoom** button on vizzes starting from the middle of the page to the botton. If I check screenshots after execution I see that vizz is visible. I tried `Sleep, Wait Until..., Scroll Into View, Focus Element, Mouse Over` but nothing helps. It always shows the same error on **Click Element ${ZOOM_CHART}** step. What am I missing?

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.93)
```

Test Case

```
Check Zooming Vizz And Reseting Back To Normal Size
    [Arguments]    ${STORY}
    ${ZOOM_CHART}=    Replace String    ${ZOOM_BUTTON}    _chart_    ${STORY}
    ${CHART}=    Replace String    ${VIZZ_CONTAINER}    _chart_    ${STORY}
    ${RESET_CHART}=    Replace String    ${RESET_BUTTON}    _chart_    ${STORY}
    Set Focus To Element    ${CHART}
    Double Click Element    ${CHART}
    Scroll Element Into View    ${CHART}
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled    ${ZOOM_CHART}    ${WFE_TIMEOUT}
    Click Element    ${ZOOM_CHART}
    Click Element    ${CHART}
    Element Should Be Visible   ${RESET_CHART}
    Click Element    ${RESET_CHART}
    Wait Until Element Is Not Visible   ${RESET_CHART}   ${WFE_TIMEOUT}
```

Comment: maybe ${ZOOM_CHART} locator refers to multiple elements where first one is not interactible (behind some other element)?

Comment: no, it has just 1 element with this locator